Error when rendering html using React template + Supabase + Nodemailer
I have an Edge Function in Supabase that periodically (via cron JOB) reads messages from a queue (pgmq) and sends emails.
So far, everything works perfectly—I managed to get it functioning and successfully sending emails. However, everything fell apart when, following a similar example from documentation, I tried to set a "cool" template to the email html.
Below is a summarized version of my Edge Function:
import React from 'npm:react@18.3.1'
import nodemailer from 'npm:nodemailer@6.9.16'
import 'jsr:@supabase/functions-js/edge-runtime.d.ts'
import { render } from 'npm:@react-email/components@0.0.31'
import { ReservationConfirmEmail } from './_templates/reservation-code.tsx'

// ...

type EmailPayload = {
  to: string
  subject: string
  content: string
}

// ...

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: <SMTP_HOST>,
  port: <SMTP_PORT>,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: <SMTP_USER>,
    pass: <SMTP_PASSWORD>,
  },
})

// ...

// This is the method that actually sends the email
const sendEmail = async (params: EmailPayload): Promise<boolean> => {
  const { to, subject, content } = params
  try {
    // Render email content using React Email
    const html = await render(React.createElement(ReservationConfirmEmail, { confirmationURL: content }))
    
     // This log is never displayed; the execution crashes before reaching here.
     console.log(html)

    // ... Send email using Nodemailer
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error)
    return false
  }
}

// ...

Deno.serve(async (request: Request) => {
  // Some code here for processing messages
  // This is where my sendEmail method is called
}  

Now, in my _template/reservation-code.tsx I have:
import * as React from 'npm:react@18.3.1'
import QRCode from 'https://esm.sh/qrcode@1.5.1'
import { Body, Container, Head, Heading, Html, Preview, Text, Img } from 'npm:@react-email/components@0.0.31'

interface ReservationConfirmProps {
  confirmationURL: string
}

export const ReservationConfirmEmail = ({ confirmationURL }: ReservationConfirmProps) => {
  const qrCodeDataUrl = QRCode.toDataURL(confirmationURL).then()

  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <Preview>Some cool preview</Preview>
      <Body style={styles.main}>
        <Container style={styles.container}>
          <Heading style={styles.h1}>Some text</Heading>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Some text</Text>
          <Container style={styles.qrContainer}>
            <Img src={qrCodeDataUrl} alt="Código QR" style={styles.qrImage} />
          </Container>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Some text</Text>
        </Container>
      </Body>
    </Html>
  )
}

export default ReservationConfirmEmail

const styles = {
  main: {
    // ...
  },
  container: {
    // ...
  },
  h1: {
    // ...
  },
  text: {
      // ...
  },
  qrContainer: {
      // ...
  },
  qrImage: {
     // ...
  },
}

Now, when the job executes the Edge Function, I always get the error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
at retryNode (file:///var/tmp/sb-compile-edge-runtime/node_modules/localhost/react-dom/19.0.0/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5867:17)
at performWork (file:///var/tmp/sb-compile-edge-runtime/node_modules/localhost/react-dom/19.0.0/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6598:19)
at file:///var/tmp/sb-compile-edge-runtime/node_modules/localhost/react-dom/19.0.0/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:7239:16
at ext:core/01_core.js:302:9

What is happening?
